# SFML - Unexpected token(s) preceding ';', missing type specifier - int assumed, Note: C++ does not support default - int

Tags: c++, syntax-error, sfml, unexpected-token

I am having 12 errors looping from:
Unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
missing type specifier - int assumed, Note: C++ does not support default - int
syntax error: missing ';' before '*
at Line 11 of Player.h

**Here is the player.h code:**

```
#pragma once
#include "GameObjects.h"

using namespace sf;
class Player : GameObject2D
{
public:
    // Classes
    GameSprite* playerSprite = new GameSprite("Textures/player.png", Vector2f(32.f, 32.f), IntRect(0, 0, 64, 64));
    PlayerAnimationPlayer* anim = new PlayerAnimationPlayer(this, "idle", 0.5f, 0, 2, "", true);

    // Sprite and animation variables
    IntRect spriteFrames[3] = {
        IntRect(0, 0, 64, 64),
        IntRect(64, 0, 64, 64),
        IntRect(128, 0, 64, 64),
    };


    // Movement variables
    sf::Vector2f direction;
    sf::Vector2f velocity;
    const float speed = 300.f;


    // Player functions
    void inputDirection();


    // Game Object functions
    void update(float deltaTime) override;
    void inputEvent(Event ev) override;
    void draw(RenderWindow& target) override;
    void free() override;


    // 2D Functions
    void setPos(float x, float y) override;
    Vector2f moveObj(Vector2f direction, float speed, float deltaTime);
};


class PlayerAnimationPlayer : AnimationPlayer
{
public:
    Player* parent;

    PlayerAnimationPlayer(Player* newParent, std::string startAnimation, 
        float newSpeed, int startIndex, int newMaxIndex, bool isOneShot, bool autoStart);
    void animation(int index) override;
};
```

**Here is the game object code (INCLUDING THE ANIMATION PLAYER):**

```
#pragma once
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>


// BASE OBJECT OF ALL GAME OBJECTS
class GameObject
{
public:
    virtual void update(float deltaTime) {}
    virtual void inputEvent(sf::Event ev) {}
    virtual void draw(sf::RenderWindow& target) {}  // This draws all drawable objects
    virtual void free() {}  // This frees all pointer variables including the class itself
};


// GAMEOBJECT USED FOR 2D AND MOVEMENT
class GameObject2D : GameObject
{
public:
    sf::Vector2f position;
    sf::Vector2f getPos();  // Returns the position

    virtual void setPos(float x, float y);  // This moves all child classes including the class itself
    virtual sf::Vector2f moveObj(sf::Vector2f direction, float speed, float deltaTime);  // Moves all child classes by direction
};


// Class for sprites
class GameSprite
{
public:
    sf::Sprite sprite;
    sf::Texture texture;

    GameSprite(std::string texturePath, sf::Vector2f offset, sf::IntRect visibleFrame);
    void setSprite(std::string newTexturePath, sf::Vector2f offset = sf::Vector2f(0.f, 0.f), sf::IntRect visibleFrame = sf::IntRect(0, 0, -1, -1));
};


// THIS ANIMATES THE OBJECTS
class AnimationPlayer
{
public:
    int maxIndex = 10;
    sf::Clock clock;
    std::string activeAnimation;

    void updateTime();  // Updates the time
public:
    bool isActive;
    bool oneShot;
    float speed = 1.f;
    int index = 0;

    AnimationPlayer(std::string startAnimation, float newSpeed, int startIndex, int newMaxIndex, bool isOneShot = false, bool autoStart = false);

    void start(std::string animation, int startIndex = 0);  // Starts the animation player
    void stop();  // Stops the animation player

    virtual void animation(int index) {}
};
```

**Here is the cpp file for animation player**

```
#include "GameObjects.h"

// CONSTRUCTOR AND MAIN LOGIC
AnimationPlayer::AnimationPlayer(std::string startAnimation, float newSpeed, int startIndex, int newMaxIndex, bool isOneShot, bool autoStart)
{
    activeAnimation = startAnimation;
    speed = newSpeed;
    index = startIndex;
    maxIndex = newMaxIndex;
    oneShot = isOneShot;
    isActive = autoStart;
    std::cout << "Constructor called" << std::endl;

    if (oneShot)
        start(startAnimation, startIndex);
}


// Updates the time
void AnimationPlayer::updateTime()
{
    if (clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() > speed)
    {
        if (!isActive)
            return;

        if (index > maxIndex)
        {
            if (oneShot)
                isActive = false;
            else
                index = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            index += 1;
        }

        animation(index);
    }
}


/// STARTS AND STOP THE ANIMATION PLAYER
// Starts the animation player
void AnimationPlayer::start(std::string animation, int startIndex)
{
    isActive = true;
    index = startIndex;
}

// Stops the animation player
void AnimationPlayer::stop()
{
    isActive = false;
}
```

**Here is the code for the player animation player cpp**

```
#include "Player.h"

PlayerAnimationPlayer::PlayerAnimationPlayer(Player* newParent, std::string startAnimation, float newSpeed, int startIndex, int newMaxIndex, bool isOneShot, bool autoStart) :
    AnimationPlayer(startAnimation, newSpeed, startIndex, newMaxIndex, isOneShot, autoStart)
{
    parent = newParent;
}

void PlayerAnimationPlayer::animation(int index)
{
    parent->playerSprite->sprite.setTextureRect(parent->spriteFrames[index]);
}
```

Ty!

Comment: Please, post your errors as text. (If in doubt, please, consult [ask] and it couldn't hurt to take the [tour].)

Comment: `PlayerAnimationPlayer` is undefined.